# JPA (Hibernate) issue with OneToOne mappedBy annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping, one-to-one

I have two tables for while I setup a oneToOne relationship.
Bill and BillSimpleEntry. (Each Bill has one BillSimpleEntry

Here is their structure

```
CREATE TABLE `bill` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ..
  ..
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_bill_groups1_idx` (`groupId`),
  KEY `fk_bill_user1_idx` (`billPayerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_b...` FOREIGN KEY (`groupId`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`) ON D     ELETE  NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_b...` FOREIGN KEY (`billPayerId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON    DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `billsimpleentry`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `billsimpleentry` (
  `..` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `..` text,
  `billId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_bill_idx` (`billId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

JPA config (snippet from the bill Entity for the oneToOne relationship attribute).

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="billId",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private BillSimpleEntry billSimpleEntry;
```

I'm trying to do a Join between Bill and BillSimpleEntry by billSimpleEntry.billId and bill.Id. But I seem to get an error.

Here is the error I get-

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne:
com.uh.br.domain.BillSimpleEntry.billId in mappedBy of    
com.uh.br.domain.Bill.billSimpleEntryry
```

Here are the entities

```
Bill.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bill")
public class Bill implements GenericObject {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5660869020353250221L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
private Long id;

...
..
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="billId")
private BillSimpleEntry billSimpleEntry;

...
getters & setters
...
}

BillSimpleEntry.java
@Entity
@Table(name="billsimpleentry")
public class BillSimpleEntry  implements GenericObject{

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private Long id;
    private Long billId;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String itemDescription;//napkin
...
...

    ...
getters & setters
...
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this bidirectional?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I think it's uni. I've replied to your answer below with my explanation. thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `mappedBy` attribute is only necessary for a `bidirectional` relationship, this element can be omitted on the annotation.  It is used on the source entity to point back to a field on the target entity that defines the relationship (contains @JoinColumn).

The `@JoinColumn` annotation should be placed upon the `billSimpleEntry` field to define the column that should be used to join the two tables.  In the case of a `OneToOne` the following applies:

> If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key
>   mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source
>   entity or embeddable.

Here is a code example:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private BillSimpleEntry billSimpleEntry;
```

Also, if the `Bill` will contain the `SimpleBillEntry` field the `BILL` table should contain a foreign key to the `billsimpleentry` table.

Comment: By Bidirection, do you mean if I want to put associations of each table in one another? In my case, I just need to pull BillSimpleEntry when querying for a Bill but not the other way around. So I guess it's a Single directional relationship? Also you've coded @JoinColumn(name="BILL_ID") instead of billId. Is there a specific reason? Thanks.

Comment: I did try your recommendation earlier - @JoinColumn(name="billId").. But I kept getting this error ---- Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: billId in billrivedb.bill-----  But billId is in BillSimpleEntry table not in Bill. I'm really confused!

Comment: Post the full source for the `Bill` and `BillSimpleEntry` entities

Comment: I have added both the entities contents to the post. Please  let me know if you need more. thx!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35708/discussion-between-user1324816-and-kevin-bowersox)