# Hibernate @OneToMany does not delete child on removal from the underlying collection

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

i am using Hibernate 4 as a ORM tool within a Angular/Spring/Oracle project.

I have a bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship in my parent class `Portfolio` as below:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "portfolio", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<PortfolioContributors> portfolioContributors;
```

and a `@ManyToOne` relationship in my child entity `PortfolioContributors`.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PORTFOLIO_ID", referencedColumnName = "PORTFOLIO_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PORTFOLIO_CONTRIBUTORS"), nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private Portfolio portfolio;
```

The problem is that if i remove a entry from the set of child entities in parent class. It does not set removed/ deleted from database.

How to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also set `null` on the other side of the relation. Something like this:

```
Portfolio portfolio = ...;
PortfolioContributors portfolioContributors = ...;

portfolio.getPortfolioContributors().remove(portfolioContributors);
portfolioContributors.setPortfolio(null);
```

Comment: Hi @Predrag, i am just doing a Hibernate save(portfolio) and the portfolio object contains a set of all the valid portfolioContribuotrs.

I am not manually removing portfolioContributors from portfolio etc.

I want the portfolioContributor to get removed automatically if it is not in Set<PortfolioContributors> of Portfolio object.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't handle the other side of bidirectional relationship, you have to do that yourself. Your use case seems to be a little specific, but you will have to `setPortfolio(null)` on the `PortfolioContributors` instance you are removing and you'll need to save it since it is the owning side of the relation.

Comment: Check out the code examples in [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades). Not exactly the same thing but close enough. Aslo check out [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23926548/4074715).

Comment: Thanks, I am not the one deciding what should be removed or added to the SET<portfolioContributors>.
User removes it in frontend and frontend sends Portfolio object to backend with a new SET<portfolioContributors> which does not have the removed portfolioContributor.  Not sure how i am supposed to figure all this out manually at backend.

Comment: I supposed orphanremoval = true was supposed to achieve the same behaviour.