# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails when deleting entry from an intermediate parent with 2 children

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'll specify my entities first so that you guys have clear picture of what I'm asking. It's very necessary, so please bear with me.

I have 4 entities:

1. `Employee` (Great - Parent)
2. `EmployeeEmail` (Intermediate Parent, child of `Employee`)
3. `EmployeeMails` (child of `EmployeeEmail`)
4. `EmployeeAttachments` (child of `EmployeeEmail`)

When I delete an entry from the Great - Parent, `Employee`, the related children entries in all of the other 3 child entities are automatically deleted. It works perfectly.

**But when I try to delete a record from the intermediate parent, i.e., `EmployeeEmail`, I get the error: `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`. This happens even though my code structure is same for both parents and I expect that even when deleting an entry from `EmployeeEmail`, only that entry and all its child entries be automatically deleted, preserving any relevant entry in `Employee (Great - Parent)`** This is the problem. How can I resolve this issue?

Here's my entity code: (The error stacktrace is after this section)

**Employee.java**

```
package core.gourabix.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<EmployeeEmail> personalEmails = new ArrayList<EmployeeEmail>();

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<EmployeeEmail> getPersonalEmails() {
        return personalEmails;
    }

    public void setPersonalEmails(List<EmployeeEmail> personalEmails) {
        this.personalEmails = personalEmails;
    }

    public void addEmployeeEmail(EmployeeEmail employeeEmail)
    {
        employeeEmail.setEmployee(this);
        personalEmails.add(employeeEmail);
    }

    public void removeEmployeeEmail(EmployeeEmail employeeEmail)
    {
        personalEmails.remove(employeeEmail);
        employeeEmail.setEmployee(null);
    }

}
```

**EmployeeEmail.java**

```
package core.gourabix.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class EmployeeEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeEmailId;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
    private Employee employee;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "employeeEmail")
    private List<EmployeeMails> mails;                              // one email account can store many e-mails.

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "employeeEmail")
    private List<EmployeeAttachments> attachments;                  // one email account can store many attachments.

    public int getEmployeeEmailId() {
        return employeeEmailId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeEmailId(int employeeEmailId) {
        this.employeeEmailId = employeeEmailId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public List<EmployeeMails> getMails() {
        return mails;
    }

    public void setMails(List<EmployeeMails> mails) {
        this.mails = mails;
    }

    public void addEmployeeMails(EmployeeMails employeeMails)
    {
        employeeMails.setEmployeeEmail(this);
        mails.add(employeeMails);
    }

    public void removeEmployeeMails(EmployeeMails employeeMails)
    {
        mails.remove(employeeMails);
        employeeMails.setEmployeeEmail(null);
    }

    public void addEmployeeAttachments(EmployeeAttachments employeeAttachments)
    {
        employeeAttachments.setEmployeeEmail(this);
        attachments.add(employeeAttachments);
    }

    public void removeEmployeeAttachments(EmployeeAttachments employeeAttachments)
    {
        attachments.remove(employeeAttachments);
        employeeAttachments.setEmployeeEmail(null);
    }

}
```

**EmployeeMails.java**

```
package core.gourabix.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class EmployeeMails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int mailId;

    @Column(nullable = true, updatable = false)
    private String mailContent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeEmailId")
    private EmployeeEmail employeeEmail;                        // many mails belong to one email account.

    public int getMailId() {
        return mailId;
    }

    public void setMailId(int mailId) {
        this.mailId = mailId;
    }

    public String getMailContent() {
        return mailContent;
    }

    public void setMailContent(String mailContent) {
        this.mailContent = mailContent;
    }

    public EmployeeEmail getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }

    public void setEmployeeEmail(EmployeeEmail employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeAttachments.java**

```
package core.gourabix.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class EmployeeAttachments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int attachmentId;

    @Column(nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private String attachmentContent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeEmailId")
    private EmployeeEmail employeeEmail;

    public int getAttachmentId() {
        return attachmentId;
    }

    public void setAttachmentId(int attachmentId) {
        this.attachmentId = attachmentId;
    }

    public String getAttachmentContent() {
        return attachmentContent;
    }

    public void setAttachmentContent(String attachmentContent) {
        this.attachmentContent = attachmentContent;
    }

    public EmployeeEmail getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }

    public void setEmployeeEmail(EmployeeEmail employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }

}
```

Here's the complete Exception Stack trace:

```
Hibernate: delete from EmployeeEmail where employeeEmailId=?
2019-12-08 01:51:54.540  WARN 2876 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2019-12-08 01:51:54.540 ERROR 2876 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`parentchildkeyrelations`.`employeeattachments`, CONSTRAINT `FK1bg8o3b2i8q2wt3vofib6n2f5` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeEmailId`) REFERENCES `employeeemail` (`employeeEmailId`))
2019-12-08 01:51:54.540  INFO 2876 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:408)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:128)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:547)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.delete(Unknown Source)
    at core.gourabix.services.EmployeeEmailServiceImpl.deleteEmployeeEmail(EmployeeEmailServiceImpl.java:25)
    at core.gourabix.controllers.EmployeeEmailController.deleteEmployeeEmail(EmployeeEmailController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1348)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2389)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3772)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1344)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`parentchildkeyrelations`.`employeeattachments`, CONSTRAINT `FK1bg8o3b2i8q2wt3vofib6n2f5` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeEmailId`) REFERENCES `employeeemail` (`employeeEmailId`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 91 more
```

Thanks a lot for reading this huge problem! Please do ask for further clarification should you need it.

And thanks, in advance!

**Edit:**

So, based on my repeated trials, it's clear that for some odd reason, Hibernate takes care to delete all children first of the Great-Parent when an entry from the Great-Parent is deleted, but fails to do so when the same action is attempted for the Intermediate Parent. In that case, it proceeds to directly delete the Intermediate Parent without deleting its children first. This is what's causing all those pesky problems. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: When you have `FOREIGN KEY constraint` you can not simply remove a record from the table that is referred by it. You should disable the constraint at first.

Comment: The constraint is required so that hibernate can delete the requested entry as well as its children. Disabling the constraint is not an option.

Comment: The reason for this is most probably a bug in your code, like for example trying to delete an EmployeeEmail which should have an attachments in its list of attachments, but doesn't because, for example, you have created the attachment and set its parent, but haven't added the attachment to the list of attachments of its parent. In that case, Hibernate doesn't find the attachments in the list of attachments of the entity to delete, and thus doesn't delete it.