# Hibernate. One to one mapping without cross references

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I investigating ways of create one to one relation between two entities in hibernate.

All examples which I have read use cross referernces:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762450/2674303

and

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/

At this example:

```
public class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Status status;
    // ...
}

public class Status {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "frn_user_id")
    private User user;
    // ...
}
```

`User` has reference to `Status` and `Status` has reference to `User`

In my opinion `Status` shouldn't know anything about `User`. I want that only `User` have reference to `Status`.

Is it possible or I don't understand something?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for `User` (remove reference to User in Status)

```
public class User {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "frn_user_id", insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private Status status;
    // ...
}
```

`insertable = false, updateable = false` should instruct Hibernate to look for `frn_user_id` in target table (Status).