# Hibernate multiple table join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have following tables

```
User (has FK_RoleKey) -> UserRole (Role Key)
UserRoleResourceAccess(FK_RoleKey) -> UserRole(RoleKey)
UserRoleResourceAccess (has FK_ResourceKey) -> Resource (ResourceKey Key)
```

Eg Row:

```
User-> EmailId = user@abc.com  | FK_RoleKey = 1
UserRole -> Role Key=1| RoleName= Admin
Resource -> Resource Key=1 | Resource name= "page1"
UserRoleResourceAccess -> FK_RoleKey =1 |FK_ResourceKey = 1
```

How can i get all the user privileges(role and resources) of a given user using hibernate criteria query.

Briefly : this is what i am trying to achieve in a single hibernate query

```
select * from User user 
LEFT JOIN UserRole userRole 
ON user.`FK_RoleKey` = userRole.`RoleKey`
LEFT JOIN UserRoleResourceAccess userRoleResourceAccess 
ON userRoleResourceAccess.`FK_RoleKey` = userRole.`RoleKey`
LEFT JOIN `Resource` resource 
ON resource.`ResourceKey` = userRoleResourceAccess.`FK_ResourceKey`
 where user.`EmailID` = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, suppose email is the PK on user table, then you have to just fetch a user from the table using HQL.

```
 String hql = "FROM User WHERE email = '"+email+"'";<br>
 TypedQuery<User> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);<br>
 User user = query.getSingleResult();
```

Hibernate automatically retrieves the other foreign key data and stores it to User if your mappings are correct. To retrieve them back, you can use...

```
String role = user.getUserRole().getRoleName();
```

Similarly for resource. Hope this helps.

Comment: but then i have to write another query to get all Resource related to Roles which is present in UserRoleResourceAccess.

Comment: could you add the code of Entity of User Table...
have you mapped the UserRoleResourceAccess to User table properly with @OnetoOne and @JoinColumn? If yes, the above stated SQL should work and you can retrieve the data like the way I have stated...

Comment: No i don't have ..check the listing in the original question.
User table has FK for UserRole
User Role table and Resource table only have PK and no FK.
UserRoleResourceAccess has FK for UserRole and FK for Resource table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762328/java-hibernate-onetoone-mapping

Check this question, this would help you.